# How to retrieve Current user name from firebase real-time database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the user name that is currently logged in from firebase's real-time databse.
I stored the information on signing up the user. I used Future Builder and it is also printing the name on the terminal but I am unable to display the username on Navigation drawer.
Kindly help me out where I am doing wrong as I am new to Flutter.
Thank you in advance!

Code for function:

```
Future<String> getUsername() async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    User cuser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    ref.child('User_data').child(cuser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      final String userName = snap.value['name'].toString();
      print(userName);
      return userName;
    });
  }
```

Code where i have used Builder:

```
Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: getUsername(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Text(
                            snapshot.data,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: const Color(0xff000000),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Text(
                            "Loading data...",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 13,
                              color: const Color(0xff000000),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Image of my Screen:

[image]

My Database where information is stored:

I want to get this 2nd user's name: Hania Salman from the database

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning the username from your getUsername() function. The return userName you have written is for the function inside then() not for getUsername(). So it should be like this

```
Future<String> getUsername() async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    User cuser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser;

    return ref.child('User_data').child(cuser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      final String userName = snap.value['name'].toString();
      print(userName);
      return userName;
    });
  }
```

Comment: isn't this and the one I have written are the same, tho it's working but I cannot figure out the difference?

Comment: i have just added the return statement you were missing at line 3 in the getusername function....

Comment: oh okay, I get it
Thank you very much :)